# Un detalle al cargar un proyecto externo en windows form

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios

estoy implementando un bloqueo en la aplicación cuando haya cierta inactividad, encontré un demo, y copie el proyecto necesario para poder implementarlo pero al arrancar la aplicación de windows form me di cuenta, que se carga el siguiente nombre..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna sugerencia de como quitarlo..

Aquí esta el proyecto que copie al final, es el resaltado en amarillo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He aquí algunas opciones para eliminar el texto "Component v2.0.0.0" que usted resalta en su pregunta:

1. En la solución, presione la combinación de teclas: `Ctrl` + `F`.
2. Seleccione `Entire Solution` para buscar el texto *Component v2.0.0.0* en toda la solución.

Creo que la segunda opción le abrirá el archivo `.Designer.cs` y allí podrá hacer el cambio.

Hecho los cambios, limpie y reconstruya `Rebuild` toda la solución.